# Symfony2 security when using i18n routing?

Tags: symfony

I'm using [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) for routing translations, with custom configuration, that is **no prefix** for all routes:

```
# app/config/config.yml
jms_i18n_routing:
  default_locale: it
  locales: [it, en]
  strategy: custom

www.example.com/contatti
www.example.com/contact
```

This is working fine, a like that bundle. Not i have to develop the admin part of the project, of course securing it. I'm stuck at security configuration (an excerpt):

```
# app/config/config.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
```

`login_path` is statically defined using `security.yml`. So, how i'm supposed to specify the correct login (localized) path? Assuming form is accessibile using:

```
www.example.com/accesso
www.example.com/login
```

Comment: Use path name for example fos_user_login that defines both /accesso and /login instead of /login in your security configuration (login_path: fos_user_login).

Answer (score 4):

As [Wojciech Jasiński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927636/wojciech-jasinski) mentioned already in the comments, you should use route name instead of pattern.

Just to bring some light...
You should define your route

```
gremo_login_path:
    pattern: /login
```

...and use it in `security.yml`

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  gremo_login_path
                check_path:  /login_check
```

See also related issues:
https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/issues/7
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3791/files